# How to set exactly the partition size in LVM Debian?

Tags: debian, lvm

I'm doing a lab with LVM and I want 10G for root

I tried with 10G and 10000000K and this is the result

root@debian:~#  df -h Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/dm-0       9.1G  810M  7.8G  10% /

and pvs give me

```
root@debian:~# lvs
  LV      VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vg_debian -wi-ao---- 9.31g
```

Why is not 10G?? What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly 10000000K is not 10 gigabytes. 10485760K is 10 gigabytes (gibibyte to be precise).

Some space are used for filesystem and LVM overheads so there will always be a different in size.

You may try with 10485760K and it should help.